# react native fails to remove ref callback attribute when unmounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using a component that i push into an array (of varying size) and controlling individual component via ref, while adding refs into an object as i need to keep track of each separately.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.stamps = [];
    this.getStampSize = this.getStampSize.bind(this);
    this.stampSize = this.getStampSize(this.props.fulfill);
    this.stampAnimation = {};
    console.log('constructing stamps');
    if(this.props.randomData){
        for (i = 1; i <= this.props.fulfill; i++) { 
            if(i<=this.props.balance){
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampNumber={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[input.props.stampNumber] = input}} randomData={this.props.randomData[i-1]} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'stamped'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }else{
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampNumber={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[input.props.stampNumber] = input}} randomData={this.props.randomData[i-1]} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'animated'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }
        }   
    }else{
        for (i = 1; i <= this.props.fulfill; i++) { 
            if(i<=this.props.balance){
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampNumber={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[input.props.stampNumber] = input}} randomData={null} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'stamped'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }else{
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampNumber={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[input.props.stampNumber] = input}} randomData={null} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'animated'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however when unmounting the component that contains stamps I get following error:
[image]

i believe it is because by the time react removes references the component is gone and cannot reach its props. However i couldn't find a solution, workaround or any other method.

Comment: Have you tried [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) to perform a cleanup?

Comment: No, i haven't.  What needs to be cleaned? this.stampAnimation or some other things?

Comment: I am not sure about that, it really depends on what you are doing with your references and how the stamps interact with the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a map to make things static via random id like below but it doesn't look nice.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.stamps = [];
    this.getStampSize = this.getStampSize.bind(this);
    this.stampSize = this.getStampSize(this.props.fulfill);
    this.stampAnimation = {};
    this.stampAnimationSupportMap = {} 
    console.log('constructing stamps');
    if(this.props.randomData){
        for (i = 1; i <= this.props.fulfill; i++) {
            var refId = this.makeid();
            this.stampAnimationSupportMap[i] = refId;   
            if(i<=this.props.balance){
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[refId] = input}} randomData={this.props.randomData[i-1]} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'stamped'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }else{
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[refId] = input}} randomData={this.props.randomData[i-1]} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'animated'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }
        }   
    }else{
        for (i = 1; i <= this.props.fulfill; i++) { 
            if(i<=this.props.balance){
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[refId] = input}} randomData={null} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'stamped'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />)
            }else{
                this.stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} ref={(input) => {this.stampAnimation[refId] = input}} randomData={null} stampSize={this.stampSize} stamped={'animated'} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampedImage={this.props.stampedImage} />) 
            }
        }
    }
}

makeid = ()=>{
var text = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
return text;
}
```